# Rotation-based solution for constructing equilateral triangle with interior point distant from vertices by 2, 3, and 4 units.

Tags: geometry

It is not difficult to construct this triangle using dynamic geometry software such as the GeoGebra diagram below. However the problem is really meant to be solved by the use of rotation: The hint given is 'consider the effect of a rotation through $60^\circ$ about one of the vertices of the desired triangle'. I am not seeing it. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that you want to create an equilateral triangle $ABC$ and a point $P$ such that $PA=2, PB = 3, PC=4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to create an equilateral triangle $ABC$ and a point $P$ such that $PA=2, PB = 3, PC=4$.

Suppose that such a triangle exists. Consider the rotation about $A$, by $60^\circ$. Let $B$ map to $C$, $P$ map to $Q$ and $C$ map to $D$. Now, observe that $PA = QA = 2$ and $\angle PAQ = 60^\circ$, hence $APQ$ is an equilateral triangle. Hence we have $CP = 4, PQ = 2, QC = 3$.

With this information, we are ready to construct the triangle. First, we create a triangle with side lengths 2, 3 and 4. This can be done by taking a line segment of length 4, and drawing circles of radius 2 and 3 using the endpoints as the centers, and taking the intersection of the circles.

Let $XYZ$ be the triangle with $XY=4, YZ = 2, ZX = 3$. Now, on the other side of $YZ$, let $W$ be the point such that $WYZ$ is an equilateral triangle. Let $WXU$ be an equilateral triangle. Then, this forms the required triangle that we want.